# The path is not a legal form when inserting record in table except a file in Files field

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a web application in which the user can insert text and files in a table. This user is a professor and what he is inserting will appear in student page. I want to insert only text, but this error "the path is not a legal form" is displayed. I think it is because I didn't specified something in case that no file is inserted in the table. Below is my code. The table is displayed using a gridview and the error appears at this line:FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(FileUpload1.FileName);

Can anyone suggest what should I do ? Thank you !

```
        FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(FileUpload1.FileName);
        byte[] b = FileUpload1.FileBytes;
        string name = fi.Name;
        string extn = fi.Extension;
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("InserareFisiere", con);
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id_fisier", (hfid_fisier.Value == "" ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(hfid_fisier.Value)));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cod_disciplina", dropdowncodcontinut.Text.Trim());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@titlul_lectiei", txtTitluLectie.Text.Trim());
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@nume_fisier", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = name;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@fisier", SqlDbType.VarBinary).Value = b;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@extensie", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = extn;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@informatii", TextArea1.Text.Trim());
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: FileUpload.FileName is the name of the file on the client. Asking to retrieve the FileInfo of a client file on the server is probably not going well

Comment: what is FileUpload1, can we see the declaration of that?

Comment: Well yeah , is this : <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
                </div>
            </div> I use this to upload a file

Comment: Sorry for the rest of the code, I need to use words in Romanian so I can provide to my professors that it's my code

Comment: where is the upload of the file event?? @PopAna

Comment: what is the error stating? @PopAna